# List Comprehension, For-Loop give differing results

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
data = load_iris()
iris = pd.DataFrame(data.data,columns = data.feature_names)
```

1. `iris['target_names'] = [data.target_names[i] for i in data.target]`
2. `for i in data.target:
       iris['target_names'][i]  = data.target_names[i]`

Why is the first bit of code is giving a different result in comparison to second?

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing your data structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The first line:

```
iris['target_names'] = [data.target_names[i] for i in data.target]
```

generates a list of of the elements `data.target_names[i]`

#### The second bit:

```
for i in data.target:
    iris['target_names'][i]  = data.target_names[i]
```

references all of the same pieces, but stores them into:

```
iris['target_names'][i]
```

The only way this would generate the same thing as the comprehension is if `iris['target_names']` were a list of the same length `data.target` and `data.target` contained the equivalent of `range(len(data.target))`.

#### Equivalent Comprehension

To build a comprehension that is the same as the loop (in 2), `iris['target_names']` likely needs to be a `dict`.

```
iris['target_names'] = {i: data.target_names[i] for i in data.target}
```

same as:

```
for i in data.target: 
    iris['target_names'][i] = data.target_names[i]
```

#### Equivalent Loop

To build a loop that is the same as the comprehension (in 1), you will need to append to a `list` like:

```
iris['target_names'] = []
for i in data.target:
    iris['target_names'].append(data.target_names[i])
```

Same as:

```
iris['target_names'] = [data.target_names[i] for i in data.target]
```